# How to mark as writable every bin/obj subfolder of a read-only directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, command, directory

I have a big directory with multiple projects inside. This directory is presently marked as Read-Only. But I want to change every "bin/obj" subfolder to be marked as writable with a windows command.

I have no skill in windows command so if someone know how to do it, it will be well appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by a bin/obj subfolder? Directories may be made read-only, but all that means os that the directory itself can't be delted by an `rd` command - it doesn't mean that the files within that directory are read-only or can't be created, deleted or altered.

Comment: all subfolders and files of this directory are presently read-only, and all I want is to make writable the bin/obj subfolders
For the moment I have this command : for /f %i in ('dir /b/ad/s') do if "%i" == "bin" attrib -r
But I can't remove the whole path of my folders with this

Answer (score 2):

To remove the read-only attribute, use

```
attrib -r /s filemask
```

where filemask may be say `*.obj` for all the .obj files. You can prefix filemask with a directoryname if you wish - `c:\wherever\filemask` and the operation will be applied to the files matching the filemask in the subtree starting `c:\wherever`. The `/s` means 'and in all subdirectories'.

`-r` removes the R/O attribute, `-h` removes the hidden attribute, `-s` the system attribute and `-a` the archive attribute. `+r, +h, +s, +a` applies the attribute.

As I've already said, Directories may be made read-only, but all that means is that the directory itself can't be deleted by an rd command - it doesn't mean that the files within that directory are read-only or can't be created, deleted or altered.

I've still no idea what you mean by a "bin/obj subfolder" - but you can apply or delete the r/o attribute from a directory if you wish - it makes no difference beyond being able to delete the directory. It does not affect any characteristic of the directory's contents. Same command - `attrib -r dirname`

Comment: additional info: `/D  Processes folders as well.`

Comment: Yeah - most important word of the lot and fumble-fingers muffs it. Must be Friday - my #2 monitor died and of course the local peddler is out-of-stock 'til Tuesday. ALWAYS on a Friday...